# Can I link gatsby Nodes without knowing the type of the referenced Node?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, schema, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I have gatsby Nodes sourced from a custom source plugin (I am working on it, too) and in my case there are some reference fields on the contents where I don't know the exact type and I cannot link them because of this.

E.g for a content:

```
{
    "Name": "Ref1",
    "Id": 3344,
    "Type": "ExampleType",
    "ReferenceToAnother": {
      "Id": 3346 // this can be anything, not only ExampleType
    }
}

{
    "Name": "Ref2",
    "Id": 3345,
    "Type": "ExampleType",
    "ReferenceToAnother": null
}
```

ReferenceToAnother can be null, or any other content (it can be a Folder or a Workspace as well, we don't know it here)

I would like to link the ReferenceToAnother with the referenced content.
I have checked the documentation of the schema customization documentation:
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization/
It would be easy if this field should be e.g. only a Folder, but in my case this information is missing and it can be also null.

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = [
    `
    type ExampleNode implements Node {
      ReferenceToAnother: [<THIS IS THE MISSING POINT>] @link(by: "Id", from: "Id")
    }

    `
  ]
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Any idea for solving this problem?
Thank you in advance!